# XMPP double message receiver Ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp

I'm writing an app that use xmpp to exchange messagge between users. If I have two devices logged with the same account,any xmpp message is received only by one device, maybe the one with the fast connection? Anyway how I can do to ensure that any message will be send to any device connected with the receiver account? I'm using ejabberd server and XMPPFramework for ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can login simultaneously in two different devices provided you are using different resource names when logging in. You can check sessions and resources the user has used to sign in on the server